# How do I instantiate an ETH token instance in my contract?

Tags: solidity

first time poster here. Have done numerous tutorials & small bits of open source work, but I'm currently working on my first true smart contract. I'm currently developing on my local network, and I am looking for a way to instantiate an ETH instance in my contract. The contract is a simple pool right now, but it should only accept ETH.

I have looked everywhere to try & find an answer to this, but I can't seem to find one anywhere & my tests keep failing because of it. What do I need to be doing differently to get my contract to reference the correct thing?

```
contract Pool is Timed {

    string public name;
    uint256 public amountDeposited;
    address private weth;

    mapping(address => uint256) public userBalance;

    event Deposit(address indexed user, string indexed name, uint256 amount);

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        uint256 _deadline,
        address _weth
    ) public {
        require(_deadline > block.timestamp);
        name = _name;
        deadline = _deadline;
        weth = new ERC20(_weth);
    }

    function makeDeposit(uint256 _amtDeposited) public payable {
        require(_amtDeposited > 0);

        weth.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amtDeposited);

        amountDeposited += userBalance[msg.sender];

        emit Deposit(msg.sender, name, msg.value);
    }
```

Am I just missing the address for ETH on my local network? And if so, that isn't going to be the same address it has on the mainnet, correct?

Appreciate any help / tips I can get here, the community has been so helpful & wonderful already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WETH is just another ERC20 token as far as the EVM is concerned, you need to create a contract for it (the contract is pretty simple, a deposit function that takes an amount of ETH ( = the native token of the chain, that would be BNB on the BSC, matic on polygon etc...) and mints WETH (or WBNB, WMATIC... you got the idea) at a 1:1 ratio to the user, and a withdraw function that takes an amount of WETH, burn it and sends the corresponding amount of ETH to the user).

Now if you want your function to use actual ETH instead of weth the syntax should be completely different. This should work.

```
  function makeDeposit() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
// userBalance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // amountDeposited += msg.value (  " amountDeposited += userBalance[msg.sender]; " is wrong, if someone deposits 2 eth and then 1 eth to your contract this would add 3 eth to amountDeposited on the 2nd call (instead of 1)). 

        amountDeposited += userBalance[msg.sender]; // This is wrong btw, you arent updating userBalance in this function, so this would just keep adding 0 to amountDeposited, see the lines that are commented out just above for a fix
    //also this isnt actually that useful, amountDeposited is just the current address balance ( you can query it with address(this).balance if you need it elsewhere in your code)

        emit Deposit(msg.sender, name, msg.value);
    }
```

The correct code for your function to work with an ERC20 token (I'll use weth as an example) would be this

```
// in your initial variable declaration 
    IERC20 weth = IERC20(WETHAddress); 

/* ...
 * Rest of your code 
 * ... 
 */

    function makeDeposit(uint256 _amtDeposited) public { // A payable function expects you to send a certain amount of the chains native token with the call (i. e. ETH), thats not what we want here
        require(_amtDeposited > 0);

        weth.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amtDeposited);
        // userBalance[msg.sender] += _amtDeposited;
        // amountDeposited += _amtDeposited (still the same problem)

        amountDeposited += userBalance[msg.sender]; // still wrong, and still kinda useless, you can query the contract balance for an ERC20 token using weth.balanceOf(address(this)) (actually this is more useful here than on the previous example since it saves an external call) 
        
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, name, _amtDeposited);
    }
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much sir! Really really appreciate all the pointers you gave, I just learned a whole lot real quick. So if I’m understanding you correctly here, if I just wanted to accept ETH I don’t even need to reference it in the constructor or anywhere, msg.value knows that it’s ETH (or native chain token)? Or would I need to still add a require check in there to ensure a user inputs ETH & not another token? And then I would need to make essentially a dummy ERC20 token contract to refer to if I wanted the pool to accept anything outside of the native chain token? Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah you dont need to do anything else, and msg.value can only refer to ETH, actually the chain doesnt support anything else than ETH natively, ERC20 tokens are just smart contracts that create objects called tokens that you can send and recieve, they absolutely dont work the same way as eth ( you cant pay for gas with them for example, transferring them isnt done the same way, theres no such thing as transferFrom for ETH... thats just a few of the differences haha).

Comment: Feel free to contact me on discord (in my bio) if you have any other questions :)